# MySQL to PostgreSQL query rewrite using "IN"?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm transferring over some queries from MySQL to PostgreSQL and I'm stumped on how to rewrite the following query to work in PostgreSQL:
`SUM(phoneid IN (1, 2, 6, 8)) AS completedcalls`

I originally thought I could just do  `SUM(SELECT phoneid FROM myTable WHERE phoneid = 1 OR phoneid = 2` etc etc, but I do not believe you can have a SELECT within a sum.

I also tried using a `WITH` query but had no luck getting that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about using `CASE`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN phoneid IN (1, 2, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
count(phoneid in (1,2,6,8) or null)
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out why this works, so probably worth an explanation: the `phoneid in (1,2,6,8)` evaluates to a boolean; if it's `true`, the `or` shortcuts, and gives `true`; if it's `false`, you have `false or null`, which evaluates to `null`; finally `count()` counts only the non-null elements, i.e. those that evaluated to true. I never knew you could do that with `or`.

Comment: @IMSoP Good explanation but I'm not sure the `or` shortcuts when `true` or if it evaluates all the expressions and applies the [truth table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html)

Comment: This is definitely the "least typing" solution.

Comment: @ebyrob I like to say the the _cleaner_.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Yes, I guess you're right, this isn't shortcutting as such - `null or true` also works, as that truth table suggests.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` may be cast to `integer`:

```
SUM(CAST(phoneid IN (1, 2, 6, 8) AS INTEGER)) AS completedcalls
```

Comment: This is a useful trick to understand as it can be used for other aggregates which aren't defined on `boolean`, e.g. `SELECT max(some_bool_column::integer)::boolean` will give `true` if at least one row is `true`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: @IMSoP You can use `bool_and()` and `bool_or()` to aggregate boolean values.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Ooh, I didn't know that! That's much more readable. :)